# How can I add an aditional header to global instance of Axios in a custom request?

Tags: javascript, axios

This is my global Axios

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { storage } from 'containers/login/utils/local-storage';

const token = storage.getToken();

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
});

    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  response.config.headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  };

  return response;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  request.headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  };

  return request;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));

export default axiosInstance;
```

In this request I need to add new header: `` invoiceLimit = `${-invoiceLimit}` ``

```
export const updateInvoiceLimit = async (
  invoiceLimit: string,
)
  : Promise<ReturnDataType> => {
  let result: ReturnDataType = {} as ReturnDataType;

  try {
    axios.defaults.headers.common.invoiceLimit = `${-invoiceLimit}`;
    result = await axios.put(`${CREDITS_URL.CREDITS}/invoice/limit`);
   
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    SnackBarUtils.error(`${(error as Error).message}. ${result.data.message}`);
  }

  return result;
};
```

When I use this:  `` axios.defaults.headers.common.invoiceLimit = `${-invoiceLimit}`; ``

header adds to the Axios defaults, but then when I call axios.put so this custom header goes away and left only global header from interceptors.

I know it's not best practice, but its customer API and I want not to make another instance of Axios but use one global instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  request.headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  };

  return request;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));
```

You are overriding all request headers with just this one:

```
{ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
```

So try spreading headers before adding the new one like this:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  request.headers = {
    ...request.headers,
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  };

  return request;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));
```

Did this solve the problem?

Comment: no, still only Authorisation header

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could just reuse the initial `axiosInstance` and the headers will be merged when you do:

```
await axios.put(`${CREDITS_URL.CREDITS}/invoice/limit`,{}, {
  headers: {
    invoiceLimit: `${-invoiceLimit}`
  }
})
```

Comment: i tried this way, but no results

Comment: @GaidashevskyiAnton, did you get any solution ?, I am stuck with same issue.